# Does a moving positive charge generate a magnetic field?

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have been wondering about how a positively charged plasma might be used to generate electrical power. So, I was wondering if, similar to a moving negative charge, a moving (or oscillating) positive charge would generate a voltage across a coil.

Comment: This question bight be a better fit for SE Physics

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on physics.SE

Comment: Why would you think it doesn't?  mag fields come from current, regardless of the carriers.

Comment: @Fred I think in this case the question should be migrated to here, and not be closed here. If we can't migrate, then our decision shouldn't be affected by the PSE topic rules.

Comment: @peterh: I agree, the question should be migrated, not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does a moving positive charge generate a magnetic field?

Yes.  The real question is why would you think it wouldn't.  Maxwell's equations are clear and have stood the test of time.

The polarity of the charge only effects the polarity of the resulting magnetic field.